# How to split string dynamically then return as array

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example, I have this string

```
recipe.Tags = "Filipino Cuisine,Easy";
```

and I want to convert it to the array below.

```
$scope.tags = [{ Name: "Filipino Cuisine" },
               { Name: "Easy"},
              ];
```

I could use the code below but then it would only work for strings with 2 tags.

```
$scope.tags = [ { Name: recipe.Tags.split(',')[0] },
                { Name: recipe.Tags.split(',')[1] },
              ];
```

Comment: this isn't an AngularJs issue, it's a JavaScript question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly use .split and .map together to obtain an **array** and convert to **array of objects**

```js
var recipe = {};
recipe.Tags = "Filipino Cuisine,Easy";
arr = recipe.Tags.split(',').map(function(item) {
  return {name: item};
});
 console.log(arr);
```

DEMO

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
    var recipe ={};
    recipe.Tags = "Filipino Cuisine,Easy";
    $scope.tags = recipe.Tags.split(',').map(function(item) {
    return {name: item};
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
 <li ng-repeat="tag in tags">
   <h1> {{tag.name}}</h1>
 </li>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

What i would do is save the tags in an array then iterate it to have your scope.tags. Like this:

```
var arrTags = recipe.Tags.split(',');
$scope.tags = [];

for(var i in arrTags) {
    var obj = {Name : arrTags[i]};
    $scope.tags.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: You can combine these separate process into one using code below

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lodash library and chain _.split and _.map to obtain an array of object.

```
var str = 'Filipino Cuisine,Easy',
myObj = _.map(_.split(str,','),(value)=>{
  return {Name:value}
});
```